# What client tools are available to manage Amazon S3 and CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I just started using the [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). What proper client tools are out there that I can use to manage my account? Like uploading files etc. Yes I am a developer, but, I am pressed for time, I just want to deploy my apps.

I came across this one [S3 Browser](http://s3browser.com/). It's almost what I am looking for.

EDIT ~ Is it possible to map a bucket as a windows Drive?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I use CloudBerry FreeWare.  Easy to use, just like FTP software.

https://www.cloudberrylab.com/explorer/amazon-s3.aspx

Jeff Atwood mentioned S3Fox Organizer on his CodingHorror blog.

http://www.s3fox.net/

[Using Amazon S3 as an Image Hosting Service](https://blog.codinghorror.com/using-amazon-s3-as-an-image-hosting-service/)

Comment: The CloudBerry app is rock solid for accessing S3 on Windows 10. I'm using it right now to back up a ton of 4k video clips I have saved in an S3 bucket to an external hard drive I have connected to my Windows 10 pc. It's running super smooth and their interface is excellent. Just create a new User under IAM called like CloudBerry and attach a new group to the user with just full S3 access and paste the Access Key and Secret Access Key into the CloudBerry app and then boom it can see all your S3 buckets and you just click the one you wanna access! Thanks man!

Comment: cloudberry url just goes to their main page now and no longer a product called freeware?

Comment: s3fox.net is down

Comment: Cloudberry url as of 5-16-2019:   https://www.cloudberrylab.com/explorer/amazon-s3.aspx

Comment: I wrote one myself, apparently fully freeware https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/storamp/9nkv1d43nll3?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: @IvanG. apparently it's freeware? Is that a surprise to you? 

Answer (score 22):

[Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) for Mac & Windows supports the full feature set of both S3 and Cloudfront distributions including custom origins. See http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/s3.

Comment: Cyberduck is not free for Mac though. =(

Comment: Downloaded current version 4.7.2 And it looks it is free for Mac users: This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

Comment: I literally couldn't figure out how to download CyberDuck on their website (lame) so I just gave up and downloaded CloudBerry from the other answer. CloudBerry works like a charm!

Comment: All you literally need to do is just click on the download button on the front page which will lead to [this page](https://cyberduck.io/download/) I hope you can take it from there

Answer (score 5):

I use [CrossFTP Pro](http://www.crossftp.com/) to handle Amazon S3 and CloudFront on the Mac, Linux, and Windows. It can handle the HTTP header metadata and log settings as well.

Answer (score 5):

While several of the mentioned client tools offer useful advanced features and/or a different approach to usability still, you can nowadays achieve most goals immediately and conveniently by means of Amazon's very own [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/), which allows you to *Access and manage Amazon’s growing suite of infrastructure web services through a simple and intuitive, web-based user interface*.

Obviously the best way to check it out is to simply explore it yourself, but the following resources allow a sneak peek:

- [Amazon S3 Features](http://aws.amazon.com/console/#s3) and the introduction [AWS Management Console Now Supports Amazon S3](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/06/aws-management-console-now-supports-amazon-s3.html) as well as [New S3 Features for The AWS Management Console](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/09/new-s3-features-for-the-aws-management-console.html)
- [Amazon CloudFront Features](http://aws.amazon.com/console/#cf) (includes a screencast) and the introduction [AWS Management Console Support for CloudFront](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2009/06/aws-management-console-support-for-cloudfront.html) as well as [Improved CloudFront Support in the AWS Management Console](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/05/improved-cloudfront-support-in-the-aws-management-console.html)

Answer (score 2):

I use the [S3 Organizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3247) plugin for FireFox to manage S3 as well as [ElasticFox](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=609) to manage my AWS instances.

Comment: Link rot has set in for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I like Cloudberry Explorer too, but had to use [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com) to create multiple distributions per bucket.  I probably missed how, but couldn't figure out how to do that with the other tools.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't need anthing to install at all. You can manage your files online from your browser wherever you are using S3fm ( http://www.s3fm.com/ ), free web based Amazon S3 file manager.

It's an Ajax app, not a hosted solution so you don't actually share your credentials with anyone.

Comment: +1 for CloudBerry. Even allows you to Set HTTP Headers for files easily. S3 Organizer lacks this feature.

Comment: S3fm.com no longer looks to be a functional web app - it currently appears to be an unregistered domain.

Comment: Use https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3fm-files/index2.html.
It is now hosted on amazon website directly